# Red line for code in IntelliJ not appearing in Netbeans - gradle project builds fine

Tags: java, intellij-idea, netbeans

In Netbeans, my code looks like this:

[image: Lines from Netbeans]

Whereas, in IntelliJ, my code looks like this:

[image]

Both IDE's run a gradle build of the project that builds without incident.

So, therefore, why should there be a wavy red line under the second line of code in the IntelliJ IDE?

I suspect this is a JDK version problem, and that perhaps my IntelliJ JDK version is wrong. Being that I am new to IntelliJ, how would I check this?

When my code looks like this, the IntelliJ IDE does not complain:

```
ContextResonance<?,S>rCtx=subscriber.getContainer().getContainer().contextResonance();
ContextReferent<?,S>ref=rCtx.getReferent();
```

But when I replace either explicit declaration with a var type (in this particular case, the first declaration), the same IDE gives me the following:

[image]

As I observe Netbeans issues no complaints whether I used the var keyword or an explicit type declaration, I think there is a problem with IntelliJ.

Are there any work-arounds for this?

In further work, I have discovered this false negative: one file is error free in IntelliJ, yet Netbeans reports an error, and the project doesn't build.

The IntelliJ code is:

[image]

The same code in Netbeans is:

[image]

Why would I want to be arsed with IntelliJ when it doesn't seem to reliably report problems with my code?

Comment: What does the error message text say when you hover on the underlined code?

Comment: IntelliJ tells me that an incompatible type is returned for a return in the call chain:

Comment: Check which language level you have in both: 'Project Settings | Project', 'Project Settings | Modules | Sources". Module language level can be differ from JDK version and trigger some inspection. Does it compile with both javac and eclipse in IDEA?

Comment: I didn't know how to navigate with the directions you gave me, but here's the output of the dialogue box one gets when one starts at the menu bar and does Window | Help:

IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-223.7571.182, built on November 30, 2022
Runtime version: 17.0.5+1-b653.14 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 5.15.0-56-generic
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 750M
Cores: 16

Kotlin: 223-1.7.20-release-201-IJ7571.182
Current Desktop: ubuntu:GNOME

Perhaps that gives you an idea of where I need to start my navigation.